# Passing arrays as parameters and make calculations

Tags: java

I have to make a `Java Program`, where a user type in the total numbers of students, so I made this code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        int numReaders = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of magazin readers:");
        numReaders = scan.nextInt();
```

Now, after adding the total number of students, we should add their names into an array:

```
//Creating an array of names, where the length is the total number entered by the user
        String[] nameStr = new String[numReaders];
        int[] ages = new int[numReaders];
        for(int i=0; i<numReaders; i++)
        {
            Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the name of reader: "+i);
            nameStr[i] = n.next();

        }
```

After that, we should add correspondingly the age of each name, so I made this portion of code:

```
for(int i=0; i<numReaders; i++)
        {
            Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the age of reader: "+i);
            ages[i] = a.nextInt();
        }

        //Display the results
        System.out.println("Number of readers is: "+numReaders);
        for (int i=0; i<numReaders; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("The name of reader "+i+" is "+nameStr[i]+ " and his age is "+ages[i]);
        }
```

After making this code, I tested it using Ideone and Command Prompt and it works properly:

[image]

Now, I need to call method according to selection of the user:
if he typed 'a' a method should be called to specify the name and the age of the oldest student.
If he typed 'b' a method called to see how many students have an age specified by the user and If he typed 'c', a function called to calculate the average age of them all.

I am new to methods so I don't know how to add arrays into methods and make statements.

Here is the full code:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        int numReaders = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of magazin readers:");
        numReaders = scan.nextInt();

        //Creating an array of names, where the length is the total number entered by the user
        String[] nameStr = new String[numReaders];
        int[] ages = new int[numReaders];
        for(int i=0; i<numReaders; i++)
        {
            Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the name of reader: "+i);
            nameStr[i] = n.next();

        }
        for(int i=0; i<numReaders; i++)
        {
            Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the age of reader: "+i);
            ages[i] = a.nextInt();
        }

        //Display the results
        System.out.println("Number of readers is: "+numReaders);
        for (int i=0; i<numReaders; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("The name of reader "+i+" is "+nameStr[i]+ " and his age is "+ages[i]);
        }

        //Choosing a statistic
        //if a:
        System.out.println("Please choose a, b or C:");
        Scanner stat = new Scanner(System.in);
        char X;
        X = stat.next().charAt(0);
        if(X=='a')
        System.out.println(X+X);
        else if(X=='b')
        //System.out.println(X);
            //Scanner newAge = new Scanner(System.in);
            //int ageToSearchFor = newAge.nextInt();
            //maxAge(ageToSearchFor);
        else
        System.out.println(X);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so to start with your user enters an `input`, for example '`a`', so let's go with this:

Firstly, you need to create the method where the name of the oldest student is displayed, so let's call it '`getOldestStudent`' - when naming methods this is the typical naming convention, starting lowercase and then moving to uppercase for each new word - try and make them as intuitive as possible.

When making the **method signature**, you need to give it its **visibility** and also what it is going to **return**. In this case, as you are only using one class, we will give it **private**, so it is only visible by this class.

Now we need to return 2 things, so we can either put these into a `string` or put them into an `array`, which is what I would recommend, so we are going to `return` an `array`. However, you want to `input` an `array` to search through, so this goes in tbe brackets as `parameters` (or `arguments`). Therefore our `method signature` is the following:

```
private String[] getOldestStudent(String[] students, int[] ages)
```

Then inside this method, you can simply do the code you need to find the oldest student, add their name and age to the array and then `return` this.

Need anymore help just drop a comment.

On a side note, you would have been better off creating a '`Student`' object and then giving this object a 'name' property and an 'age' property and then simply making an `array` of `students` and `getters` and `setters` (or `accessors` and `mutators`) for these properties.

Comment: how to access the initial arrays of names and ages inside those methods, that's my problem

Comment: You need to call the method and pass your arrays into it, like so: getOldestStudent(nameStr, ages). Then inside this you can access them using these names.

Answer (score 1):

James Lloyd's covers your question pretty well, I thought I might add some input as I think you are struggling with some principles.

At first, I would do as James advised and create a class `Student` that stores the values for each person.

```
public class Student {
    public String name;
    public int age;

    // Constructors allow you to create a new Object and set some variables
    // when you create it.
    public Student (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I used `public` to avoid getters and setters for this explanation, but I'd use `private` most had I to write it by myself.

Anyways, that way you only have to use one instead of two arrays (and `name` and `age` are connected with each other, e.g., you know the age of a student you know the name of, whereas with two different arrays it could happen that you don't know if `nameArray[0]` belongs to `ageArray[0]`.

So you have an array `Student[] students = new Student[numReaders];` and you can set each `Student` after reading the input, i.e., after reading the `name` you call `students[i] = new Student(name);` If you want to set the `age` of a `Student` afterwards you can do so by using `student[i].age = age`.

Now that we have filled our array, we can advance to your actual question.

```
char method;
method = stat.next().charAt(0);
// I think switch is a little easier to read for such cases
switch(method) {
case 'a': Student oldest = getOldestStudent(students);
          if (oldest != null)
              System.out.println(oldest.name);
          break;
case 'b': //another method
          break;
default: // equals to else as if none of the other cases was fulfilled
         break;
}
```

Now you can write your own method for each scenario you have to cover.

```
public Student getOldestStudent(Student[] students) {
      // at first we check some cases that do not require further checks
      if (students.length == 0) {
         System.out.println("No students have been specified"); 
         return null; // this might lead to a NullPointerException so check the return Object whether it is null before doing anything with it
      } else if (students.length == 1)
         return students[0];
      // no we have to see which students if the oldest in the regular case
      // the first student will be used for comparison
      Student oldestStudent = students[0];
      for (int i = 1; i < students.length; i++) {
          // see if our current student is older
          if (oldestStudent.age < students[i].age)
              oldestStudent = students[i];
      }
      return oldestStudent;
}
```

This way you can easily access the `Student`s name afterwards (see above in the switch). You can build all your methods like this by passing the array to the methods and iterating through it. Depending on whether you want to return one or more `Student`s (as it might vary between the different methods) you have to change the return type from `Student` to `Student[]`.