# the ouptput of a function is always equal to the inital one

Tags: java

After getting an answer [from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35081463/passing-arrays-as-parameters-and-make-calculations/35082235#35082235), I tried to make a method that returns the oldest member from a list of arrays that contains name and age of each person.

So in the main method I added those lines:

```
        char X;
        X = stat.next().charAt(0);
        if(X=='a')
            System.out.println(X);
            oldest(nameStr, ages);
        if(X=='b')
            System.out.println(X);
            //Scanner newAge = new Scanner(System.in);
            //int ageToSearchFor = newAge.nextInt();
            //maxAge(ageToSearchFor);
        if(X=='c')
            System.out.println(X);
```

And I created the following method `oldest()`:

```
public static void oldest(String[] str, int[] ageInt)
    {
        int maxAge=0;
        String maxName="";
        for(int i=1; i<ageInt.length;i++)
        {
            int temporary=ageInt[0];

            if(ageInt[i]>temporary)
            {
                maxAge = ageInt[i];
                maxName = str[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The listener "+maxName+ " is the oldest with an age "+maxAge);
    }
```

But I am getting the same result:

> the listener  is the oldest with an age of 0

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
I changed the if into switch case and still the same problem:

```
        System.out.println("Please choose a, b or C:");
        Scanner stat = new Scanner(System.in);
        char X;
        X = stat.next().charAt(0);
            switch(X){
                case 'a':
                    //System.out.println(X);
                    oldest(nameStr, ages);
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    System.out.println(X);
                    //Scanner newAge = new Scanner(System.in);
                    //int ageToSearchFor = newAge.nextInt();
                    //maxAge(ageToSearchFor);
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    System.out.println(X);
                    break;
        }
```

Comment: What's in the arrays?

Comment: see the link, first array contains name of each reader, the second is their ages.

Comment: Might it be as simple as a missing bracket? Try to change if(X=='a')  System.out.println(X); oldest(nameStr, ages); to if(X=='a') {System.out.println(X); oldest(nameStr, ages);} (That's why I never omit brackets)

Comment: I removed the IF and now I have switch cases but with the same problem please see the edited section of my question

Comment: Where is the declaration of `nameStr` and `ages`?

Comment: I still don't see any input after following the link. We need to know what's in the arrays.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean sir ? nameStr contains names and ages contains age of each name in nameStr, the user add some names into arrays, then into another arrays he will add their ages then the function returns the name and the age of the oldest reader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't doing the correct comparison. See corrected, commented code below.

```
public static void oldest(String[] str, int[] ageInt)
{
    int maxAge=0;
    String maxName="";
    for(int i=0; i<ageInt.length;i++) // start from zero
    {
        if(ageInt[i]>maxAge) // compare to the current max
        {
            maxAge = ageInt[i];
            maxName = str[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The listener "+maxName+ " is the oldest with an age "+maxAge);
}
```

Comment: your code giving the last entered age but not the biggest

Comment: It works now, thanks sir. yeah I need to get the biggest age of age arrays, it works now thanks.

Comment: Depending on what exactly it is you want to do, can I suggest you take a look at HashMaps. This will be better than two separate arrays in most cases.

Comment: Sir, if I put inside the for loop a counter, how to return it, I am always getting that counter = 0 because it is initialized before for loop as 0

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if(X=='a')
        System.out.println(X);
        oldest(nameStr, ages);
```

to

```
if(X=='a') {
        System.out.println(X);
        oldest(nameStr, ages);
}
```

and please stick to surround `if` with brackets *every time*.

Comment: While this is certainly a good idea, and probably corrects an error in the original code, it utterly fails to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

In the event the first value of ageInt[] is the greatest value, then maxAge and maxName will never be changed, since those contents are only set in the event the value of ageInt[i] is greater than the temporary value.  So instead of initializing your variables via the following.

```
int maxAge=0;
String maxName="";
```

Initialize them as such:

```
int maxAge = ageInt[0];
String maxName = str[0];
```

Furthermore, ensure that you are declaring

```
int temporary=ageInt[0];
```

Outside of the for loop, otherwise you will always be setting temporary to ageInt[0], which will produce an issue if say

ageInt[0] < ageInt[1], and

ageInt[0]< ageInt[2] < ageInt[1]

As your maxAge will be set to ageInt[2] on the its iteration through the for loop.  A better way to write this to avoid such an issue would be to check against your current maxAge instead of temporary.

```
for(int i=1; i<ageInt.length;i++){
    if(ageInt[i]>maxAge){
        maxAge = ageInt[i];
        maxName = str[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I contemplated this solution, but ultimately went the alternate route of starting `i` at 0 because it won't fail when the arrays are empty.